# Can i use Diebold Mariano test for comparison of 2 models across multiple time series?

Tags: forecasting, accuracy, diebold-mariano-test

I have 2 models (for simplicity, let's call them AR(1) and MA(1)) each making `1 day ahead forecasts` of time series.

If I had only 1 time series I would just use the `Diebold-Mariano` test to compare the predictive abilities of the models.

But let's assume I have multiple time series. For each of them I have estiamted `AR(1)` and `MA(1)` models. With Diebold-Mariano test i could test if `AR(1)` is better on series 1 and series 2 separately. I would like to test the performance of the models on aggregate though.

If the AR(1) is much better on series 1 compared to MA(1), and they are comparable on series 2 (or MA(1) could be even slightly better) I would like to test whether in total over both series AR(1) is better. Is that possible?

**To make a more exact example:** Assume I am forecasting stock returns for multiple companies. For given companies some models perform better than others. It could happen that from 10 companies model `A` performs much better than model `B` for 4 of them and worse for 2 of them. Can i find out if overall, across all my 10 companies, `A` is better fit then `B`?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use **DM.test** function from **multDM** library. for this, you have forecast values of the two models along with the test values.